# Connection error while downloading nltk data

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to download nltk data on windows with different option like `nltk.download()`,`nltk.download('all')`, `nltk('popular')` but getting same error

```
                     [WinError 10060] A connection attempt
[nltk_data]    |     failed because the connected party did not
[nltk_data]    |     properly respond after a period of time, or
[nltk_data]    |     established connection failed because connected
[nltk_data]    |     host has failed to respond>
```

I have tried to download packages manually from (https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) but once i clicked download, the site can't be reached due to the same error "raw.githubusercontent.com took too long to respond". can anyone tell me any alternate way to do it, i have been stuck here for 2 days now.